# Method goes into an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call a recursive method and quit calling it when the `while` condition is `False`. Though, what I get is when `COUNT_NUM` is 0 the method just keeps repeating itself and returns both `print`s

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = input("Enter URL: ")
COUNT = input("Enter count: ")
POS = input("Enter position: ")

def retrieveNames(url, count=1, position=1):
    """ Retrieves a name from url """

    POSITION_NUM = int(position)
    COUNT_NUM = int(count)

    if (POSITION_NUM< 1): return

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    tags = soup("a")
    countNum = COUNT_NUM - 1

    tag = tags[POSITION_NUM-1]
    print("COUNT:", countNum > 0)
    while countNum > 0:
        retrieveNames(tag.get("href"), countNum, position)

    print(tag.contents[0])
    return

retrieveNames(URL, COUNT, POS)
```

Comment: You probably want to replace `while count > 0:` with `if count > 0:`. Otherwise the `while` loop will run forever if `count > 0`. Or alternatively set `count -= 1` within the `while` loop instead of `count = COUNT_NUM - 1` outside.

Comment: Ok, the declared `count` variable should have a different name, but `count > 0` returns False. So how does it keep looping? :/

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Could you elaborate on that? Not sure how it does it because the while loops condiiton is false

Comment: Your loop is essentially `while count > 0: do nothing`. You're not decrementing `count` at all. Once it starts, it never stops.

Comment: @RolandJegorov `count > 0` evaluates to `False` for _some_ of the calls to `retrieveNames`, namely when you pass it an argument `count` which is zero. However during your `while` loop you do this forever.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an infinite loop because you are calling your function recursively, which means that your variable countnum is now present in multiple scopes: the original function call and the recursive calls. This means that whatever happens to countnum when you call retrieveNames doesn't affect the value of countnum within the while loop. Thus you will never get out of the while loop. 
So what you want to do is either return countnum:

```
while countNum > 0:
    countNum = retrieveNames(tag.get("href"), countNum, position)
return countNum
```

OR change the while statement to an if statement.